# Is there an "official" tag for Windows batch script questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

There doesn't seem to be a commonly-accepted tag for question about Windows batch/shell scripts.  We see a mix of various tag combinations, any mix of `[windows][dos][dos-batch][shell][script]` and so on.

They likely account for a fair number of questions when put together, but it's very difficult to gather them all under one tag.

Is this even a problem?  *nix script questions have a similar problem, although most are gathered under `[bash]`.

So, SO,  what should we be using?

Comment: And the follow-on question... what do we do about the large number of "mis-tagged" ones?

Answer (score 2):

I vote for [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) or [batch-scripting](/questions/tagged/batch-scripting) which already has **1,384 questions**. This is platform neutral  (MS-DOS is a really outdated term, but it's not typical Windows functionality either) and makes it immediately clear what syntax is being used (as opposed to PowerShell and other Windows scripting technologies).

Comment: Is that specific enough?  I thought that `[windows-batch-scripting]` would be ideal.

Comment: @skaffman I'm not sure about the `windows` part. I think `batch` is the generally accepted term (also because of the .bat extension)

Comment: +1 It's much better than [ms-dos].

Comment: 'batch' and 'batch-scripting' are not terms that are specific to Windows. Using those terms as if they were causes confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The word "batch" is a general computing term that in the minds of many is not specific to Windows `.BAT` files.

I agree with the OP that there is a cognitive dissonance in allowing questions about Windows .BAT files to own the tag [batch](/questions/tagged/batch)

In the mind of many of us the term **batch** has a far wider non-OS specific meaning that implies the execution of a (typically large, long running) non-interactive data processing job that could be initiated manually or via a scheduler.

The batch tag description as it stands describes current usage on the SO site well in that it refers Windows `.BAT` files and for some reason SQL scripts. (as opposed to UNIX shell scripts or VMS DCL scripts or whatever scripting languages are used on IBM Mainframes or now that I think of any long running non-interactive data processing job irrespective the technology used to produce the running process)

Batch is to Windows .BAT script files as Program is to .c C program source files. It's a general term which on SO is applied to a specific concept.

I would vote to change **batch** to **.BAT** if that was possible or anything that made it clear that Windows .BAT files were being tagged for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I think [ms-dos](/questions/tagged/ms-dos) is the correct tag.

- [ms-dos](/questions/tagged/ms-dos)    **171** questions
- [dos-batch](/questions/tagged/dos-batch) **114** questions

Comment: Naah. That is the *last* tag that would come to my mind

Comment: @Pekka: Agreed. Just because it's the most popular one, doesn't make it right :)